# ClientSocket NOT listening

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

Im flabbergasted.

I took code from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoServer.java

for the server. And
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java

for the Client. I made minor changes. Mostly so that there is no back and forth echoing. Rather the Server should constantly with 2 second delays send same string. But I just cant understand why the client isnt working.
It sends the Exception message:
*Couldn't get I/O for the connection to 127.0.0.1*
I run the server with: java 6788
and the client with: 127.0.0.1 6788
I tried other ports.

I do this in eclipse so I set the arguments in Runconfiguration before running the classes. I start the server first. I tried in terminal outside of eclipse. Nothing makes it work.
Basically, the client should connect to server and output with System.out.println() what the server in turn outputs to the client. But nothing happens.
**what is wrong?**

**Client:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println(
                "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try (
            Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));

        ) {
            String userInput;

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("recieved: " + in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } 
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EchoServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java EchoServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        InetAddress add = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(add.getHostAddress());
        try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket =
                new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());                   

        ) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.println("HELLO!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment I eventually found a solution. BufferedReader.readLine() "blocked". When reading from a file it returns a line after reading up to a newline character, if I understand it correctly.
But since it was "A steady flow" from server with no newlines, it just kept "reading" and never returned a String.

I then tried using BufferedReader.read() method, that reads character by character, and returns after each char (thus never blocking). It then prints each character as it arrives, also it listens for a newline being sent from server, and once a read character equals a newline, it then prints a newline instead. Sort of emulating the "read line" behaviour I was expecting from original question.

**Reading part of client:**

```
    while(true) {
        character = (char) reader.read();
        if(Character.isISOControl(character)) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("%c", character);
        }           
    }
```

**Sending Part of Server:**

```
private String message = "HELLO\n";
...
while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                writer.write(message);
                writer.flush();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to send the answer to the client.

Add a `out.flush();`

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.println("HELLO!");
    out.flush();
}
```

Comment: and oracle server sample uses autoFlush (PrintWriter second argument ) `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);`

Comment: Adding flush does not help. Maybe its a must. But code is still not working as intended. I get no output what so ever from Client.

Comment: @brat Did you add true to PrintWriter constructor as 2nd argument to your server code? I did it to your code and run it then client get 'recieved: HELLO!' multiple times. I run `java EchoServer 1999` first and `java EchoClient 127.0.0.1 1999`. If you don't still success, try remove class file (EchoServer.class) first and rebuild it.

Comment: Weird. Because I tried both the constructor argument and the flush() method approach. I guess you did additional changes? I eventually found that BufferedReader.readLine() "blocks", because... well it could not know when a line was ending as opposed to when reading from a file. I opted for BufferedReader.read(), which reads char by char in a loop, prints them, then adds a newline once it recieves a control char from server. This didnt "block".